# How to get the latest video of a channel on YouTube (without gdata.youtube.com or an API key)?

Tags: python, youtube

Since gdata.youtube.com is now retired, I tried using [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). However, I found out I had to pay. Is there any other way I can do this?

I did it like this before:

```
inp = urllib.request.urlopen(r'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?start-index={0}&max-results=50&alt=json&orderby=published&author={1}'.format(1, args) )
resp = json.load(inp)
inp.close()
returnedVideos = resp['feed']['entry']
```

Comment: Where does it say you need to pay?

Comment: Don't you need to pay to create a new Google Developers project?